# Extending the CakeRequest Object

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a web application written in CakePHP that needs to read request data from a JSON payload as opposed to standard application/x-www-form-urlencoded data.  I would like to be able to access this data via the standard $this->request->data methodology.  Is there a supported way to extend the CakeRequest object so that it is able to accept requests in this format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can customize the CakeRequest object's functionality:

Insert the following into app/Config/bootstrap.php:

```
/**
 * Enable customization of the request object.  Ideas include:
 *   * Accepting data in formats other than x-www-form-urlencoded.
 */
require APP . 'Lib' . DS . 'Network' . DS . 'AppCakeRequest.php';
```

Create app/Lib/Network, and add AppCakeRequest.php:

```
<?php
/**
* AppCakeRequest
*
* Allows for custom handling of requests made to the application.
*/

class AppCakeRequest extends CakeRequest {
    // Do your magic, and be careful...
}
```

Edit app/webroot/index.php:

```
$Dispatcher->dispatch(new AppCakeRequest(), new CakeResponse(array('charset' => Configure::read('App.encoding'))));
```

Be careful, make sure you know what you're doing, and good luck.